# Micronaut 4, KSP, AllOpen: Need to add explicit `open` to the method

Tags: micronaut, kotlin-allopen

I'm attempting to port a Micronaut 3 app to Micronaut 4, but the `allOpen` seems to have mysteriously stopped working.   I can add `open` to the class and function definitions and things work as designed.   I double checked the annotations and everything seems correct.

org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen:1.8.22

It's just a mystery why allopen would stop working while the Micronaut-3/kapt builds continue to function normally.   As the google.devtools.ksp plugin is complaining, and not much else has changed, I suspect it is the most likely culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Micronaut 4 doesn't force you to migrate to KSP, you can continue using KAPT with Micronaut 4.

The problem that you observe is about KSP not currently supporting Kotlin's allopen gradle plugin. This problem is covered in the following issues:

https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/9764
https://github.com/google/ksp/issues/1576